# Android mdnsresponder using native api returns kDNSServiceErr_ServiceNotRunning (-65563)

Tags: android, android-ndk, bonjour, mdns

We want to discover a service using native code. The native code is within a dynamic library that is called from ndk code. 
We have successfully tested the code using iOS and mac os. On android we are running into this issue:

```
09-14 04:00:48.274 25997-25997/com.my.App W/com.my.App: dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
09-14 04:00:49.274 25997-25997/com.my.App W/com.my.App: dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
09-14 04:00:50.276 25997-25997/com.my.App W/com.my.App: dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
09-14 04:00:51.276 25997-25997/com.my.App W/com.my.App: dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mdnsd Socket:46 Err:-1 Errno:2 No such file or directory
09-14 04:00:51.277 25997-25997/com.my.App W/AppLogic_Cpp: WARNING::Error in MDNS, code: -65563
```

I know that this error stands for `kDNSServiceErr_ServiceNotRunning`. We have tried starting the service from android as mentioned here: [BONJOUR IN ANDROID APPLICATIONS](https://www.andriydruk.com/post/mdnsresponder/) using `context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);` but this does not solve the issue.
The article is aimed at using the library directly form java, which is not what we are doing, so it is only partly applicable.

I should also clarify that we have build mdnsresponder ourself from code. Could this issue be related to our build?

Even if I completely run service discovery in android using `NsdManager` the daemon is not found / the issue persists for the native code. `NsdManager` finds the service just fine.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit 1: Spelling and some clarification about `NsdManager` tests.

Comment: I have the same issue. You may have to acquire a multicast lock but for me   didn't work either. Note that you also need to set the permissions ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: We have already set all these permissions. There has to be a way to get this to work.

Comment: make sure you run/test the app on a real device... I was using an emulator and it didn't work but now on a real device(Google Pixel 2, latest updates) it works.

Comment: I have tried multiple devices. All with android 8 and newer. Maybe I should try an older android Version.

Comment: Update: after several tests it stopped working for no reason/no change made... IMHO android seems to be just trash so I can't tell if it's policy issue or if they have bugs.

Comment: Update: works again after I restarted the device...

Comment: Interesting. I will try to figure out more on my end when I have time.

Comment: I'm stuck with this same issue.  I believe I've done everything mentioned above but still get error -65563 back.  This is with Android 10 (on a real device).  Anyone have any further comments on how to make this work?

Comment: @btschumy I think this will never work as android does not allow us to start a deamon. We ended up using the Android specific Multicast implementation and piping the results into c++.